# Fastest way to get from one permutation to another (with distances between elements)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

[image]Imagine that I have some rows of shelves. Some shelves have items on them. Some may be empty. Imagine also that I have computed the shortest paths between each location (using Dijkstra's algorithm, for example). I want to rearrange the items on the shelves to some fixed permutation that I have in mind. Is there an algorithm to find the optimum way to rearrange the shelves i.e the sequence of relocations for which I will have to travel the least distance? Let's also say I can only carry one item at a time, although I would also be interested to find out how the algorithm would change if we allowed multiple people each carrying an item.

Comment: There sure is some dynamic programming based solution using some form of edit distance (maybe the Jaro-Winkler distance? I'm not very familiar with it though)

Comment: @MikeEarnest I have added a picture of an example. The first part of the picture is a graph of the original configuration. The second part is a graph of the target configuration. Red nodes are occupied locations in the shelf. Black nodes are unoccupied. Letters are the items (item A, item B etc) and the numbers are distances between nodes. The third part is a rather crude drawing of a bird's eye view of what the shelves would physically look like.

Comment: So, if I wanted to move `J` to its target position, could I do that directly, or would you have to move `I` out of the way first?

Comment: @MikeEarnest You could move J directly to its target position because its target position is originally unoccupied. But if you wanted to move Q to its target position, you would have to move I out of the way first.